# In Julia, how do you recast variable type at a given memory location?

Tags: memory, types, julia

I'm using FortranFiles.jl to interface with files written by an old Fortran code.  At one part of a given file, string arrays are cast as a single array of Float64's (or Float32's, depending) and stored as a Fortran record.

I can't seem to find documentation on how to do this in the manual or on-line.

Thus, to read the information, I'm using something like:

```
fid = FortranFile("myfile.dat")
read(fid, (Float64, 10))  # which actually represents 5x 16-char strings
```

How does one go about recasting the memory from an array of Floats, a constraint given due to using FortranFiles.jl and the way the file is stored, to a contiguous section of memory known to be characters by Julia?

Think of something similar to turning a `(void *)` in C to `(double *)`, etc...

Thanks.

**Edit** - Fixed inaccurate comment above about how many 16-char long strings were being read in.

Comment: Try `reinterpret` from the standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Krastanov,

Thanks.  Using `reinterpret` was essentially the answer.  There were some nuances I discovered, however.  (n.b. this is for Julia 1.1.0)

When dealing with reinterpreting between types of different sizes, you need to put the source in an array even for one element.

E.g., `reinterpret(UInt8, 1.23)` won't work.  But `reinterpret(UInt8, [1.23])` will work.  Not a problem for my example as `read` returns an array, but something I noticed when I was playing around at the REPL.

Additionally, the `Char` type is a Unicode type and treated as a 32-bit data type, hence me using `UInt8` above.

The final answer looks like:

```
fid   = FortranFile("myfile.dat")
tmp   = read(fid, (Float64, 10))  # This return an array
chars = [Char(i) for i in reinterpret(UInt8, tmp)]
```